# Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged не работает

Tags: xamarin, android, monodroid

Здравствуйте!

Имеется listView, который я пытаюсь обновлять с помощью NotifyDataSetChanged(), но listView при этом не обновляется. Я использую такой способ:

```
ChatAdapter = new BubbleAdapter (this, Messages);
if(listViewChat.Adapter == null) {
    listViewChat.Adapter = ChatAdapter;
} else {
    ChatAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Если я обновляю способом ниже, то мой listView автоматически прокручивается наверх, что мне не нужно:

```
ChatAdapter = new BubbleAdapter (this, Messages);
listViewChat.Adapter = ChatAdapter;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените

```
ChatAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

На

```
listViewChat.Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

И догадайтесь сами, почему так работает.

Короче говоря, представьте себе, что `listViewChat` - это машина, а `ChatAdapter` - это ее водитель.

```
ChatAdapter = new BubbleAdapter (this, Messages);
```

Создаете нового водителя

```
if(listViewChat.Adapter == null) {
        listViewChat.Adapter = ChatAdapter;
    } else {
        ChatAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Если в машине нет водителя, то посадить в машину новосозданного водителя. Иначе новосозданный_водитель.завести машину. (ChatAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged()). Но новосозданный водитель ведь не сидит в машине! там сидит старый!!!

```
if (Messages.Count != 0) {

    if(listViewChat.Adapter == null) {
        ChatAdapter = new BubbleAdapter (this, Messages);
        listViewChat.Adapter = ChatAdapter;
    } else {
        ChatAdapter = (BubbleAdapter)listViewChat.Adapter;
        ChatAdapter.SetMessages(Messages);//реализовать метод, который бы записывал новые значения в адаптер
        ChatAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: в том, что вы создаете ChatAdapter = new BubbleAdapter (this, Messages);, не делаете  listViewChat.Adapter = ChatAdapter;, а потом вызываете ChatAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();. То есть вы создаете адаптер, не выставляете его в ListView, вызываете у адаптера NotifyDataSetChanged, и удивляетесь, почему же ListView не обновляется

Comment: Точнее "ChatAdapter является "поле", но используется как "тип"

Comment: я обновил ответ, там надо было не (ChatAdapter), а  (BubbleAdapter)

Comment: Хорошо, а что, примерно, должно быть в методе SetMessages. Я так понимаю, то же, что и в конструкторе?

Comment: Потому, что данные обновляются, но не отображаются в listView

Comment: все зависит от вашего кода.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, дальше как нибудь сам.